# Which Linux OS is the most compatible to deploy a meteor app to a domain listening on port 80?

Tags: meteor, deployment, operating-system, nameservers

The OS should be a linux OS. Which one would be the most compatible to deploy a meteor app to a domain listening on port 80?

Comment: Anything is good as long as you know how to deploy. One easy way http://meteor-up.com/

Answer (score 1):

Meteor app has quite a documentation on their official site and offers different methods to deploy your app, either use:

- Galaxy, the service built by Meteor Development;
- Meteor Up which is a third party open-source tool;
- Docker;
- Custom deployment;

So I'd suggest to check up their docs: https://guide.meteor.com/deployment.html